# Using and executing the missing complex functions of Mathematica in Wolfram script *.wls

Tags: notebooks, scripting, free-wolfram-engine, interoperability

I have the following Mathematica notebook on this link [notebook](http://31.207.36.11/BD_equations.nb)

I was told that the binary **wolframscript** couldn't understand some complex functions of Mathematica.

First, I would you like to convert this notebook file to `.wls` format and be able to run it directly on terminal.

Is it possible that **wolframscript** execute the converted notebook, even if this latter uses complex functions like `DSolve` or other functions that doesn't exist natively in Wolfram script language ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. `wolframscript` and evaluate any WL expression that does not involve specific front-end functionality. `DSolve` will work fine.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi . Thanks for your quick answer. Unfortutanely, I can't manage to convert the file given in the link of my post above. For the moment, if I perform a "Save as..." under format `.wls`, I have all the command lines commented, I don't understand why. If you could indicate me how to convert the notebook to a working `.wls` file, this would be fine.
Regards

Comment: Only `Initialization` cells are saved without comments in `.wls` or `.m`, `.wl`. Select all the input cells you want to save then Ctrl+8 on a Mac or from the menu Cell / Cell Properties / Initialization Cell.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi .  Is there a way to convert in an automatic way the notebook to Wolframscript by doing systematically the trick Ctrl+8 for all input cells in notebook ?

Comment: Evaluate `NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Input", All, CellStyle]`. That will select all `Input` cells, then Ctrl+8 to set them all to `Initialization` cells.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi . Thanks, could I perform this command under Mathematica or directly from the terminal ?

Comment: It has to be evaluated in Mathematica in the notebook that you want to save as `.wls`.

Comment: and how to mention the notebook to convert in this command line under Mathematica ?

Comment: The expression uses `EvaluationNotebook[]` so whatever notebook it is evaluated in. Try it.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi . Sorry I am new to Mathematica, how can I open a shell when I have opened the notebook ? Is the shell already present inside the notebook ?